# Is FA 18:2 undifferentiated the same as linoleic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, fats

On wiki, linoleic acid has the code number **FA 18:2 cis,cis-9,12**. But then what exactly is FA 18:2 undifferentiated?

Answer (score 3):

It's part of an old nomenclature used in the fatty acid industry.  FA 18:2 translates to **F** atty **A** cid with **18** carbon atoms and **2** double bonds.  You can read more about these "Lipid numbers" [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatty_acid#Nomenclature).  So to answer your question, there are number of fatty acids with 18 carbons and 2 double bonds, linoleic acid is just one of them.  FA 18:2 includes linoleic acid, but is not limited to just linoleic acid.